# Shorten a list of tuples by cutting out loops?

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a function that generates a list of tuples like:

```
[(0, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (1,3), (2, 4), (3, 5), (4, 5)]
```

which are used to represent a path of tiles (row, column) in a game I'm making.

The function that I use to generate these paths isn't perfect, since it often produces "loops", as shown below:

```
[(2, 0), (2, 1), (1, 2), (0, 3), (0, 4), (1, 5), (2, 5), (3, 4), (3, 3),
 (3, 2), (4, 1)]
```

[image]

The path above should instead look like:

```
[(2, 0), (2, 1), (3, 2), (4, 1)]
```

[image]

These paths can contain any number of loops, which can be of any size and shape.

So my question is, how do I write a function in python that cuts the loopy list and returns a new, shorter list that does not have these loops.

My attempt below:

```
def Cut_Out_Loops(Path):

    NewList = list(Path)
    Cutting = True

    a = 0
    for Cords in Path:
        a += 1

        try:
            for i in range(a + 2, len(Path)):
                if (Path[i][0] == Cords[0] and abs(Path[i][1] - Cords[1]) == 1:
                    NewList = NewList[0:a] + NewList[i:]
                    Path = list(NewList)
                elif Path[i][1] == Cords[1] and abs(Path[i][0] - Cords[0]) == 1:
                    NewList = NewList[0:a] + NewList[i:]
                    Path = list(NewList)
                elif abs(Path[i][0] - Cords[0]) == 1 and abs(Path[i][1] - Cords[1]) == 1:
                    NewList = NewList[0:a] + NewList[i:]
                    Path = list(NewList)
                elif abs(Path[i][1] - Cords[1]) == 1 and abs(Path[i][0] - Cords[0]) == 1:
                    NewList = NewList[0:a] + NewList[i:]
                    Path = list(NewList)
                Cutting = False
        except IndexError:
            Cutting = True
```

Comment: Nice question, but what have you tried? Please post your code.

Comment: what do you call "produces  a loop" ?

Comment: Ok, I'll add it. I didn't know it would be appropriate to add it since it is pretty flawed.

Comment: A loop exists when the path can be shortened while still retaining it's endpoints. The first image shows a path that can be shortened to the one represented by the second image.

Comment: It sounds like it might be better to use a search algorithm that finds better paths. Perhaps you're using depth-first search where breadth-first would be more appropriate, or something like that.

Comment: I know, I really should be using an A* algorithm or something, but given that I haven't been programming in python long I don't understand the examples I've seen online. So I made up my own algorithm that's really inefficient. Even so, I know that an answer to this question would help me understand the novel ways people might try to solve this type of problem.

Comment: A bit off topic, but in terms of code style, uppercase names like `NewList` are usually reserved for class names. Typical python style for variable naming is lowercase with underscores between words like `new_list`. The only reason I mention is you'll eventually run into naming collisions with classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although your definition of a "loop" isn't too clear, try this

```
def clean(path):
    path1 = []
    for (x1,y1) in path:
        for (i,(x2,y2)) in enumerate(path1[:-1]):
            if abs(x1-x2) <= 1 and abs(y1-y2) <= 1:
                path1 = path1[:i+1]
                break
        path1.append((x1,y1))
    return path1
```

It definitely works for your example:

```
 >>> path = [(2, 0), (2, 1), (1, 2), (0, 3), (0, 4), (1, 5), (2, 5), (3, 4), (3, 3), (3, 2), (4, 1)]
 >>> clean(path)
 [(2, 0), (2, 1), (3, 2), (4, 1)]
```

That said, it is just the most straightforward of brute force solutions. The complexity is quadratic.

Comment: For my purposes, this works great. I tried to over-complicate things since I thought brute force was a big "no no", but since my paths are, at most, 50 entries long, brute force is acceptable. Still, I'd love to see it if there is a more efficient solution for paths that are thousands of entries in size.

Answer (score 1):

How long are your paths? If they're all under 1000 elements, even a naive brute-force algorithm would work:

```
path = [
    (2, 0),
    (2, 1),
    (1, 2),
    (0, 3),
    (0, 4),
    (1, 5),
    (2, 5),
    (3, 4),
    (3, 3),
    (3, 2),
    (4, 1)
]


def adjacent(elem, next_elem):
    return (abs(elem[0] - next_elem[0]) <= 1 and
            abs(elem[1] - next_elem[1]) <= 1)

new_path = []
i = 0
while True:
    elem = path[i]
    new_path.append(elem)
    if i + 1 == len(path):
        break
    j = len(path) - 1
    while True:
        future_elem = path[j]
        if adjacent(elem, future_elem):
            break
        j -= 1
    i = j

print new_path
```